# Programmatically manipulating assembly metadata

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, clr, metadata

Is there any way (API or library) that allows modification of a C# assembly's metadata?

I'd like to take an existing .NET assembly (C#, using .NET 4.5) and programmaticaly modify its metadata, saving the result back to disk (either as a new assembly, or modifying the existing one).

I know that such a thing may be possible, although not automatically via an API, through tools such as Reflector or *ILDASM/ILASM*

.

Is there an API i can use to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Reflexil](http://sebastien.lebreton.free.fr/reflexil/) might help you.
A related article on Codeproject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20565/Assembly-Manipulation-and-C-VB-NET-Code-Injection)